# Error when calling Out-File: Cannot bind argument to parameter FilePath

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a html file, and then a function that appends text to the file, but it errors during debug as well as execution.

I feel something is not correct in the `-Append` section or maybe the string?

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
At D:\Automation\Fragementation\EVSQLFragmentationReport.ps1:83 char:11
+     Out-File $fileName -InputObject "" -Append
+              ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Out-File], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
```

The entire code is very big and I have the parts below for your recommendations:

```
Function writeHtmlFooter {
    Param($fileName)
    Out-File $fileName -InputObject "</body>" -Append
    Out-File $fileName -InputObject "</html>" -Append
}
```

Comment: You're calling `writeHtmlFooter` with an empty argument. Please update your question with that part of the code where you call the function. Include enough information so that we can see how the argument (presumably a variable) is populated.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Something like `writeHtmlFooter -fileName "C:\folder\file.txt"` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes my calling was errorneour, rectified now and its working perfect,